# Problemas em c# na chamada de telas que nem o professor conseguiu resolver

Tags: c#, winforms, image

Mens, faço um curso técnico de DS, estou em fase de TCM e queria saber se conseguem resolver ou me ajudar com esse problema:

Seguinte: Estou fazendo um CRUD em c# win forms e me deparei com um erro onde quando chamo um formulário através de um botão, o mesmo ao invés de abrir com um click faz-se necessário o uso de dois(double click para abrir telas). Para chamar outro formulário uso esse seguinte método:

```
    private void abrirJanela(object conteudo)
    {
        if (this.panelfake.Controls.Count > 0)
            this.panelfake.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        Form janela = conteudo as Form;
        janela.TopLevel = false;
        janela.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelfake.Controls.Add(janela);
        this.panelfake.Tag = janela;
        janela.Show();
        pictureBox2.Hide(); //esconde imagem do home
    }
```

No método percebe-se que  eu descrevo uma parte para fechar as telas abertas(ou pelos menos acho que é isso), só que acontece que não fecha, quer dizer, fecha com dois clicks. Creio que esteja sobrepondo.

Abaixo estarei deixando um curto vídeo onde mostrarei o problema:

https://youtu.be/wWMURMs4mvY

Desde já,
grato

Comment: Sem mais detalhes não tem como te ajudar. O problema pode estar naquele if inicial, pode estar no momento de abrir a tela, qualquer coisa...

Comment: está meio complicado de entender, mas vamos lá...
você está querendo refazer a funcionalidade de MDI Parent / Child, que é abrir o form dentro de outro form... ?
junto disso, seria necessário 2 cliques para abrir o form, e se outro form for aberto, o anterior deve fechar ?
obs. Remover o form do painel fake não irá fecha-lo.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tentava da seguinte forma:

```
    private void abrirJanela(object conteudo)
    {
        //programação defensiva
        if(!(conteudo is form))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro no objeto recebido");
            throw new Exception();   //configurar a exception pretendida ou usar um return
        }
        if (this.panelfake.Controls.Count > 0)
            this.panelfake.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        Form janela = conteudo as Form;
        janela.TopMost = true;
        janela.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelfake.Controls.Add(janela);
        this.panelfake.Tag = janela;
        pictureBox2.Hide(); //é mesmo necessário? Eu acho que talvez não...
        janela.Show();
    }
```

Mas outra forma melhor será:

```
    static TipoJanela janela = null;

    private void abrirJanela()
    {
        if (this.panelfake.Controls.Count > 0)
            this.panelfake.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
        janela = new TipoJanela();   //cria um novo objeto do tipo janela ao invés de receber um. Se houver parâmetros, estes podem ser lidos de  valores estáticos ou usando o construtor
        janela.TopMost = true;
        janela.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.panelfake.Controls.Add(janela);
        this.panelfake.Tag = janela;
        pictureBox2.Hide(); //é mesmo necessário? Eu acho que talvez não...
        janela.Show();
    }
```